# How to remove invalid syntax error message in editing Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio, razor, razor-declarative-helpers

In Razor ( in site master page and in views)  javascript strings with dynamic content are used, like

```
@inherits ViewBase<EntityBase>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $("#xx").attr('title', @Html.Raw(Json.Encode("<>.")));
```

Microsoft Visual Studio Express for Web 2012 flags trailing parenthese as error:

[image: syntaxerror]

How to fix this ?

Construction ´@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Res.I("somestring")))´ is used in may places to dynamically translate texts for javascript. I() returns text im user languge.
How to create some helper so that code is simllifid ? I created view common base class and added function there so that  view contains only I("somestring") but this is not available in Razor master layout file Site.cshtml specified in  ´Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Site.cshtml"´

How to fix this error and use simple function I("somestring") which returs encoded javascript string ?

ASP.NET MVC3 , C#, jquery, jquery ui are used.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: Both questions are related. I expected that maybe creating function `I("stringtotranslate")` and using it instead of this removes read alerts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio's Javascript language service does not recognize Razor markup within Javascript code blocks.
These errors are false positives, and will not occur at runtime.

Comment: Pages contain lot of javascript code into which strings in user language are injected dynamically using this method. So every injected message text throws this error, whole page looks red. How to fix those false positives ?

Comment: @Andrus If you still need to get rid of those false-positives, I have posted an answer that addresses just that. Your code may run just fine even if you ignore them, but getting rid of useless `Warning: Syntax Error` allows you to more easily identify more pressing warnings/errors.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode("<>."))
```

you can write

```
"@Html.Raw(Json.Encode("<>."))"
```

---

Unfortunately, this only works if you need a string. I haven't yet found a way to circumvent those false positives for other data types like int or bool, short of casting them:

```
var myInt = Number("@myInt");
var myFloat = Number("@myFloat");
```

or in the case of boolean, checking their value for "true":

```
var myBool = "@myBool".toLowerCase() === "true";
```